# Tiny Death Star: What can ONLY be bought with Imperial Bux?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

Which items can ONLY be bought with Imperial Bux, and cannot be gotten through patience/gold coins? And what are the benefits of each of them?

For example, I don't believe it's possible to upgrade your elevator without Imperial Bux. What else is there?

Comment: Imperial bux also come with patience, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From personal experience I know you are correct that the only way to obtain elevators is with Imperial Bux. Apart from that there is nothing you can only buy with Imperial Bux.

Some of the other rare things you can buy with bux are:

- Unlock specific "celebrity" bitizens
- Specific shops
- Level upgrades (otherwise only available through VIPs)

Buying the salvage droids for 15 or 25 Imperial Bux does give a better change for a rare.

It is also possible to get Imperial Bux for free.

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question. Plus you cannot buy levels with Bux. You can only hurry their production.

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt you **can** purchase a specific level with bux, if you want it, from the store -- it still takes time to add but reduced cost and without the randomness of just add a type of level.

Comment: Ah, yes. Good point.

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt I edited the answer a bit

Comment: I've added to the answer. I just remembered: You should also mention upgrading levels. That can only be done via VIPs or IB.